# Python enumeration dropping the last element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working off this article [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) trying to parse some command line arguments but the script I built keeps dropping the last argument.

To keep it simple I reproduced the problem like so:

```
import getopt

argv = ["-c", "config", "-o", "hello", "-e", "fu bar", "-q", "this is a query"]
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "c:o:e:q", ["cfile=", "ofile=", "entry=", "query="])

for opt, arg in opts:
    print(opt, arg)
```

Here is what I get for output:

```
-c config
-o hello
-e fu bar
-q
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's generally recommended to switch to `argparse` these days. Which has nothing to do with your question, but that's why this is a comment. :-)

Comment: I would recommend switching to `click`. Yes, it is a third party library which means an extra dependency but feels much more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon (`:`) is not a separator, it needs to follow each argument as stated [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt):

> *shortopts* is the string of option letters that the script wants to recognize, with options that require an argument followed by a colon (`':'`; i.e., the same format that Unix `getopt()` uses).

Therefore you should change `"c:o:e:q"` to `"c:o:e:q:"`

The tutorial you linked to uses it the same way too.